# SparkApp unable to load Aws Java Sdk definitions

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, apache-spark, amazon-s3, apache-spark-sql

My spark application is not able to load the `AWSCredentials` class and displaying the message - 
 `Failed to load com.pipeline.ana.SparkApp: com/amazonaws/auth/AWSCredentials`

I have these imports -

```
import com.amazonaws.auth.AWSCredentials;
import com.amazonaws.auth.BasicAWSCredentials;
import com.amazonaws.auth.AWSStaticCredentialsProvider;
import com.amazonaws.client.builder.AwsClientBuilder;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3ClientBuilder;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3;
```

Created s3Client like this -

```
AWSCredentials credentials = new BasicAWSCredentials("access_key", "secret_key");
AmazonS3 s3Client = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard()
                    .withEndpointConfiguration(new AwsClientBuilder.EndpointConfiguration("https://10.10.1.225:19443", "region1"))
                    .withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(credentials))
                    .build();
```

is used to put the object (string present inside the java RDD). When I do `mvn clean package`, build is successful but `spark-submit` is not able to find the AWS classes.

My maven dependency `com.amazonaws.aws-java-sdk.1.11.595`. 
How can this be resolved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I am using IntelliJ ide, it is sometime the caching issue. Simply delete the project metadata directories from project folder and import the project. The build.sbt would reload the dependencies without any failure. My issue is solved with this naive approach.